# Why doesn't the logging info be printed out to the screen?

Tags: python

I am using PyCharm and want to test the logging:

```
import logging


logging.info("This is the logging info ...")
```

I suppose this should print out the 'This is the logging info ...' to my console when I run the program, but it didn't.

I don't have any other setting or configuration on logging. Where is the logging info going?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your logger, give it an output file and everything

```
logging.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
Logs a message with level INFO on the root logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Answer (score 0):

The default level for the root logger is `WARNING`. You need to configure the logger first to change its level. For example,

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("This is the logging info ...")
```